# Understanding example Spotipy usage - necessity of inner `for` loop

Tags: python, spotipy

I'm trying to use the Spotify API with the spotipy library, but I'm not understanding the code example from this article:

https://towardsdatascience.com/making-your-own-discover-weekly-f1ac7546fedb

```
sourcePlaylist = sp.user_playlist("<source user>", "<Source Playlist ID>")
tracks = sourcePlaylist["tracks"]
songs = tracks["items"] 
while tracks['next']:
    tracks = sp.next(tracks)
    for item in tracks["items"]:
        songs.append(item)
```

I understand the data returned by the API is in nested dictionaries.  I don't understand why the inner for-loop is necessary.

If `songs = tracks['items']`, then the for-loop within the while-loop is basically saying:

```
for song in songs:
    songs.append(song)
```

since `tracks['items']` was originally in the list `songs` anyway. Why append `tracks['items']` to `songs` when `songs` is, by definition, equal to this data?

Comment: I am not very familiar with this API but can guess that `songs` is initialized with `tracks['items']` which are all tracks from the source playlist, and then, while `next` is True (which I guess is some condition on those tracks), the `next` set of tracks is fetched and added to the `songs` database. The while loop is necessary because you're doing `sp.next(tracks)` so you need to first make sure that this is possible to do. About the `for` loop, notice that you reassign `tracks` so it's not like doing `songs.append(song)`

Comment: Ok so the first initialization is basically like the first page of tracks, and the sp.next(tracks) and the for loop is appending subsequent pages of tracks to songs?

Comment: This is what I am taking from this, but again, not really familiar with this api. To make it more readable and easy to understand, he could do instead of the loop, simply `songs.extend(tracks['items'])` and then maybe it will be less confusing. as each iteration of the while loop you take the `next` tracks and extend songs with them

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the inner for-loop is required, and why it makes sense to repeatedly add `tracks["items"]` to the list `songs`, is that the Spotify API uses *pagination* to avoid having to return more data than necessary in API responses. So `tracks` is different on each iteration of the while-loop.

It [mentions it in the Spotify API Documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/#pagination), but it's also something that happens across APIs generally. For example, if you have an API endpoint that returns a list of songs on Spotify, it will be impractical/impossible to return *every* song on Spotify in a single response. Instead, this data will be broken down into *pages*. Someone who wants to retrieve all songs from Spotify would keep track of their current "page" and request the next page each time, while users who only want a subset of the songs on Spotify might just make one request and ignore the paging functionality entirely.

Annotating your example with comments:

```
songs = tracks["items"]  # set songs to be the songs from the initial page of data
while tracks["next"]:  # user-playlist response says there are still pages left
    # tracks["next"] will be an actual URL that will return the next page of results
    tracks = sp.next(tracks) # set tracks to the next page of data after the current one
    # sp.next is a utility method Spotipy provides
    for item in tracks["items"]:  # append each song on the current page to `songs`
        songs.append(item)
```

Might also help to see what `sp.next` actually does:

```
class Spotipy(object):

    ...

    def next(self, result):
        """ returns the next result given a paged result
            Parameters:
                - result - a previously returned paged result
        """
        if result['next']:
            return self._get(result['next'])
        else:
            return None
```

The example from the article in a clearer way (like Tomerikoo says with `extend`):

```
full_tracks = []
while tracks:
    full_tracks.extend(tracks["items"])
    tracks = sp.next(tracks)  # eventually will be `None` on the final page
```